# Web Service Server from wsdl in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I would like to create a server in c# (Visual Studio 2017) with given wsdl and xsd files. My application should be the server and a client will use the methods that wsdl describes.
I used the visual studio tool wsdl.exe to generate a cs file that contains every method I expect and a service class, so in my main I can declare an object of that class. Now, how I can "open" my server to "listen" for some client? I really cannot figure how I can do it and I really cannot found anything helpfull on the web.
Of course, you understand that I am not really an expert of c#, so where can I find some information about this particular stuff? Someone can give me a hint to reach my goal?

Thank you all very much.

Comment: In client side You can add as a references. Didn't you try  to do that methord?

Comment: Where is your server?  Is it a project inside your solution rather than a server hosted somewere? In the first case, if you run in debug the solution, visualstudio will start iis in localhost and then you can get the address

Comment: Well, I have to implement the server side, the client that will connect to my application is somewhere else… The thing I miss, I belive, is how I can start my server...